# How do I implement a model by code in EMF?

Tags: java, implementation, eclipse-emf

I have created a Model in EMF. I  also managed to generate code from it (`.genmodel` file), I looked into the files, I kinda understand the implementation of the model, edit and editor plugin.

Yet I fail to understand, how I make my own instance of the metamodel by code. I understand the way the code is written, but I don't know where to put now my own stuff so it will be called.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by where to put your own stuff? And did you already have a look at the respective Factories that have been generated in your model plugin? They allow you to create instances of your metamodel by calling the respective `create` method, if that's what your are looking for.

Comment: I mean how do I call my implementation? how do I load it into my "model"? I know how to create the code, but I don't really know how to use it. what makes it run?

Comment: Have you tried to generate RCP Application? (in .genmodel propeties you can set Rich Client Platform = true)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: take a look at the [EMF Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321331885). The book will help you understand how to use the generated code and how to construct models (Part IV).

There are two ways to create a model: programatically or using the generated editor. The editor allows you to create a model in a tree view. To use the editor you need to run the editor plugin as an Eclipse aplication (right click -> run as). Once in the nested eclipse you should be able to use your editor to craete a model.

The model by itslef is not very usefull and I assume you want to load the model to read its contents, modify them, query them, etc. The first important thing to know is that EMF models are persisted as XMI files (name.xmi). The global extension is "xmi", but in the genmodel you can your oreffered extension (lets assume is "soq"). XMI is an extension to XML, so if you look at an XMI file with a text editor it will look just like an XML. To load an emf model the basic code is:

```
ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
URI uri = URI.createURI("file:/c:/data/model.soq"); 
Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(uri);
try 
{ 
    resource.load(null); 
    System.out.println("loaded"); 
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{ 
    System.out.println("failed to read " + uri); 
}
```

The resource will now contain all the elements of your model. Each of them will be an instance of the the respective java class that the genmodel generated. To get the contents of the resource (the elements) you can loop over `resource.getContents()` or over `resource.getAllContents()`, the difference is that the latter will iterate over all the model contents, the former only over the first level. Then, for example, you could test of type and do stuff:

```
for (EObject eo : resource.getAllContents()) {
    if (eo instanceof MyEmfClass2) {
        System.out.println("Found an element of MyEmfClass2");
    }
}
```

The other thing you can do is create instances of your metamodel classes and add them to a resource. For example, you can do this to generate a model from reading the information from another source (db, file):

```
MyEmfClass2 c2 = soqFactory.createMyEmfClass2 ();
c2.name = otherDataSource.name;
ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl(); 

URI uri = URI.createURI("file:/c:/data/newm.soq"); 
Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(uri); 
resource.getContents().add(c2); 
try 
{ 
    resource.save(null); 
    System.out.println("saved"); 
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{ 
    System.out.println("failed to write " + uri); 
}
```

Note that the specific factory name and methods depend on your metamodel. Also this code assumes you are running from the Eclipse runtime application (that is, your metmodel plugins are installed in the Eclipse IDE). If you want to run without the runtime eclipse or in a standalone environment additional precautions need to be taken:

```
EcorePackage.eINSTANCE.eClass();    // Makes sure EMF is up and running
resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap(). 
put("soq", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());  // make sure EMF knows how to load your models
YourPackage.eINSTANCE.eClass();    // Makes sure all your factories are registered and classes loaded
```

The EMF metamodel and generated code is just a "data model". So out of the box it will just help you store and manipulate data. Any additional functionality would have to be coded around it.

On a final note, the [EMF Forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=108) on the Eclipse site has an active community and the EMF developers are more likely to monitor questions there than at Stackoverflow.